# how keeping format/order when downloading/exporting a table

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

We've built several dashboards in icCube Reporting 5.x and now the users do some sorting and sometimes download/export the data of a table and want to keep the format of the measures and the configured sorting when opening as a excel file.
What can we do to make this possible?

Comment: Please describe the problem and/or add an example of the issue.

Comment: We usually use Google/Table. 
One Use Case is to have rows with shops and columns with several measures (e.g. count sales, revenue and conversion rate) with different format_strings (e.g. #,##0.00 € and #,##0 and 0.00 %). 
Default order is "revenue" and now we want to order by "count sales" and then export the table as a excel file. 
If we do this, the table in the excel file is ordered by "revenue" again and not by "count sales" and the format_strings has been killed (e.g. revenue as "3412,07999974489" and not "3412,08" and conversion rate as "0,021029622" and not "2,10 %").

Answer (score 0):

The FORMAT_STRING seems supported in the latest version of icCube (6.8.7). As for keeping the sorting not sure this is supported yet. Please contact their support for reporting it.